# jQuery - variable defined inside $.each, but it's undefined outside

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach

I have the following code, which is driving me nuts:

```
$.each(originalSteps, function() {
                    if($(this).attr('id') == 'ps_attributes_step_'+(parseInt(triggered_step)+1))
                    {
                        alert('testing validity');
                        var newOne = $(this);
                    }
                });
                console.log(newOne)
```

Now, the alert is being triggered, but newOne is undefined outside the loop. Any Solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is becuase you have declared the variable inside. Change your code as below.

```
var newOne;
$.each(originalSteps, function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'ps_attributes_step_'+(parseInt(triggered_step)+1))
    {
        alert('testing validity');
        newOne = $(this);
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(newOne);
```

Edited to add return false. See comment below for explanation.

Comment: I would suggest adding `return false;` after assigning `newOne` to break out of the `$.each` early.